# Add tags to logback configuration

Tags: xml, logback

I am trying to write custom appenders which have a special configuration and I would need to make corresponding tags for their xml configuration.  It is clear from logback manual how this should be done: by adding new rules to the configurator as explained here: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/onJoran.html

My problem is how to add this rule when the configurator is not created directly, but when it's created by the slf4j binding. When you first access a slf4j-api a `LoggerFactory`, slf4j-api will look for an available binding in the classpath. If you correctly have `logback-classic` the binding will be found, it's the class `StaticLoggerBinder`. Its initialization shows

```
  try {
      try {
        new ContextInitializer(defaultLoggerContext).autoConfig();
      } catch (JoranException je) {
        Util.report("Failed to auto configure default logger context", je);
      }
      // logback-292
      if(!StatusUtil.contextHasStatusListener(defaultLoggerContext)) {
        StatusPrinter.printInCaseOfErrorsOrWarnings(defaultLoggerContext);
      }
      contextSelectorBinder.init(defaultLoggerContext, KEY);
      initialized = true;
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      // we should never get here
      Util.report("Failed to instantiate [" + LoggerContext.class.getName()
          + "]", t);
    }
  }
```

If we look inside the `ContextInitializer.autoconfig()` we see that if an initialization file is available, it delegates the work to

```
public void configureByResource(URL url) throws JoranException {
    if (url == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("URL argument cannot be null");
    }
    if (url.toString().endsWith("groovy")) {
      if (EnvUtil.isGroovyAvailable()) {
        // avoid directly referring to GafferConfigurator so as to avoid
        // loading  groovy.lang.GroovyObject . See also http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LBCLASSIC-214
        GafferUtil.runGafferConfiguratorOn(loggerContext, this, url);
      } else {
        StatusManager sm = loggerContext.getStatusManager();
        sm.add(new ErrorStatus("Groovy classes are not available on the class path. ABORTING INITIALIZATION.",
                loggerContext));
      }
    }
    if (url.toString().endsWith("xml")) {
      JoranConfigurator configurator = new JoranConfigurator();
      configurator.setContext(loggerContext);
      configurator.doConfigure(url);
    }
  }
```

As you see, there is no way to add rules to the configurator used to parse the logback.xml when it is created. The only solution I have found is the following. First, I put a new rule in all my logback configurations where I need my custom tags and then inside this rule code, I add other rules.

```
  <newRule pattern="*/appender/asynclogger" actionClass="com.logentries.logback.joran.AsyncLoggerAction"/>


    <appender name="LE" class="com.logentries.logback.LogentriesAppender">
        <asynclogger>
            <logentries-httpput ssl="false" account="myAccount" key="myKey"/>
            <ignore-exceptions/>
        </asynclogger>
        <facility>USER</facility>
        <layout>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>
```

I have the feeling I am doing this in a sub-optimal way, is there a better solution ?

Comment: The new rules are integrated dynamically to the running configurator instance when the XML file is read. I probably don't understand your question.

Comment: I have explained better my problem

Comment: If you just want to set custom bean properties on your appender, then you don't need to do anything special at the Joran level. For example, to configure a [ZMQSocketAppender](https://github.com/tlrx/slf4j-logback-zeromq/blob/master/src/main/java/org/tlrx/logback/appender/ZMQSocketAppender.java), you just add [elements corresponding to the properties](https://github.com/tlrx/slf4j-logback-zeromq#configuration).

Comment: This is for basic java properties I guess. I am trying to add custom properties which are typically beans or enums

Comment: why are you mentioning slf4j? if logback.xml is being read then Joran is the configurator doing the reading. (Joran ships with logback-classic.)

Comment: detailed explanation given :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does logentries-httpput correspond to some field of LogentriesAppender? If yes, just write:

```
  <appender name="LE" class="com.logentries.logback.LogentriesAppender">
        <logentries-httpput class="fully-qualified-class-name-for-logentries-httpput">
           <ssl>false</ssl>
           <account>myAccount</account>
           <key>myKey</key>
        </logentries-httpput>
        <ignore-exceptions/>
        <facility>USER</facility>
        <layout>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>
```

Joran will do the wiring on its own. You don't need to specify any rules.

Comment: does the notation <tag class="abcd"> always work? Can I used it nested as well? Thanks

Comment: Yes, nesting of such elements is supported.

Comment: This is actually not what I am seeing: 14:35:41,907 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@13:71 - no applicable action for [asynclogger], current pattern is [[configuration][appender][asynclogger]] <appender name="LE" class="com.logentries.logback.LogentriesAppender">
        <asynclogger class="com.logentries.net.NettyBasedAsyncLogger">
            <logentries-tcptoken ssl="false" token="bla" />
            <ignore-exceptions/>
        </asynclogger>

Comment: Can you post LogentriesAppender and NettyBasedAsyncLogger, in particular the fields declared in each class? Moreover, you cannot use XML attributes to configure fields, you need to use XML elements, e.g.  <logentries-tcptoken ssl="false"..